# Error running heroku local

Tags: python, django, heroku, local

> I would like to ask if you know this error I have during my heroku local command, Thanks for the help. My goal here is just to create my first django project to be deployed online. xD

cmd: **heroku local**

```
(venv_heroku) C:\Python27\venv_heroku\heroku-django\test_app>heroku local 
    forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
    web.1  | '"C:\Users\Raguine\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\IEUpdate\logagent.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
    web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I have already installed everything and requirements, I hope :D.
And here's my installed dependencies. I hope nothing is missing.

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.7.10
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
psycopg2==2.5.2
static3==0.6.1
```

And this is my **.gitignore** file

```
venv
 *.pyc
staticfiles
```

This is my **Procfile** looks like

```
web: gunicorn test_app.wsgi --log-file -
```

While my **settings.py** and **wsgi.py** was copy-pasted from the guide I am following. from heroku website :

> https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

(Sorry about this 'coz I'm just a newbie here. :D)

Please help me with this.

PS: I am using **Python (2.7.9)** and **virtualenv (13.1.2)** and *heroku* (heroku si running on my cmd) installed and declared it on the environment variables.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my logagent.exe? Is it infected or a trojan virus? T.T

Comment: You should definitely run anti-virus programs, and search google how to remove this particular worm.

Comment: My anti virus is Microsoft Security Essentials and up to date.  I already scanned the folder of logagent.exe(folder where it is located), but it has no files or any virus.

Comment: Question is going really out of topic, but you definitely have something wrong with your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you already dont have a `Procfile.windows` under your root of the project, create a file by that name. Add the following line into the file.

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
```

When running the heroku local, use the following command

```
heroku local -f Procfile.windows
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies